# C#/Azure function: Fastest way to serve a file?

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function that serves a file with a custom name:

I'm doing this:

```
string outputName = fileName.Substring(0,fileName.Length-4)+"."+clientKey+".msi";

    try
    {
        var res = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var fs = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open);
        res.Content = new StreamContent(fs);
        res.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-msi");
        res.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = outputName
        };
        return res;
    }
    catch
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
```

Is this the fastest way?

Comment: That looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

That is going to be the best way to serve a file. If the files are extremely large, you may need to add `res.Headers.TransferEncodingChunked = true;` to help keep the download from failing.